# regarding generating a graph of this type in R

Tags: r

how to generate the following graph (which is generated using Excel) in R?

[image]

Comment: [Quick-R: Bar plots](http://statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really provide data etc. but...

```
require(ggplot2)

data<- data.frame(xaxis = letters[1:10], yaxis = rnorm(10))
enter code here
ggplot( data, aes(x = xaxis, y = yaxis))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity",  colour = "blue", fill = "blue") +
ggtitle( "RP model variables")
```

Check this out for more info http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/